# char datatype input is being converted to a different thing when process in c++

Tags: c++, string, queue, character

I am trying to input a string in the code using the `char` datatype. But whenever the input is being processed in the function. It breaks the character into maybe ascii(not so sure since I am not familiar). For example the

> 'z11'

turns to

> 49'1'

when I check it in the debug function of the compiler. Below is the code that I am working on. They are all separated in 3 files.

**Header**

```
typedef struct node {
    char x;
    struct node *next;
}item, * queue;
void enqueue(queue* q, char x);
```

**Implementation .cpp**

```
void enqueue(Queue* q, char x) {
    Queue temporary;
    Queue proc;

    temporary = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(item));
    temporary->x = x;
    temporary->next = NULL;

    proc = *q;
    if (proc == NULL) {
        temporary->next = *q;
        *q = temporary;
    }
    else {
        while (proc->next != NULL)
            proc = proc->next;
        proc->next = temporary;
    }
}
```

**main .cpp**

```
void main() {
    Queue list = NULL;
    enqueue(&list, 'z11');
    display(list);
}
```

is it possible to make it behave like a normal/regular string so that I can easily manipulate it like I can concat, get the specific character in the input like "z11", ill get letter "z" for checking purposes? Basically I just want to add the input "z11" as a whole in the list. And If I display it it should be "z11" also.

Comment: `char` is not a string, it's a single character. Use `std::string` for strings.

Comment: You don't need to use `typedef` for structures in C++. And variables can be passed by reference instead of passing a pointer. You seem to be programming as if you're using C.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the quick reply sir. how do I implement the std::string in the header and cpp?

Comment: Read a C++ tutorial on structures and classes.

Answer (score 1):

`'z11'` is a *character constant* and its value is implemention-defined because it contains multiple characters.

`char` can store only one character. You should use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to store strings.

`malloc()` will not work for `std::string` (and structures containing that). You should use `new` for allocating objects in C++.

Also note that strings (string literals) are represented like `"z11"` (double quotation marks instead of single).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response sir. I am kind of new in programming. Do you have a link or something that I can use as reference on implementing the "new" for allocating objects ?

Comment: Extra detail: The type of the constant `'z11'` is `int`.